# Export Magento Bundle Products Values in CSV

Tags: magento, csv

I want to export some bundle product values in csv. Like Title, Min_val, Max_val, Default_val.

I want to do that by Dataflow-Advance Profile option and for that i also create xml but its not working. see xml below. If is there any other way to export bundle products please share.

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
<var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
<var name="filter/type"><![CDATA[bundle]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
<var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
<var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
<var name="map">
<map name="sku"><![CDATA[sku]]></map>
<map name="attribute_set"><![CDATA[attribute_set]]></map>
<map name="name"><![CDATA[name]]></map>
<map name="id_bundle_options_0_title"><![CDATA[id_bundle_options_0_title]]></map>
</var>
<var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
<var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
<var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
<var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
<var name="type">file</var>
<var name="path">var/export</var>
<var name="filename"><![CDATA[BundleAttrib1.csv]]></var>
</action>`
```

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/KilQDuqiD0

Comment: from where i want to get these values look in this link.